# Confusion about the definition of expected value

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a discrete random variable, i.e a function from some set of events $\Omega$ to some finite set $E$. $X(\Omega)$ denotes the image of $X$.

The definition I have seen for the expected value of $X$ is the sum

$E[X]=\sum_{x \in X(\Omega)} xP(X=x)$

Now consider two random variables $X$ and $Y$ defined on $\Omega$. Using the definition above, we have that

$E[XY]=\sum_{a \in XY(\Omega)} aP(XY=a)$

So for example if $X(\Omega)=Y(\Omega)=\{2,4\}$ then $XY(\Omega)=\{4,8,16\}$.

Then

$E[XY]=4P(XY=4)+8P(XY=8)+16P(XY=16)=4P(X=2,Y=2)+8P(X=2,Y=4)+8P(X=4,Y=2)+16P(X=4,Y=4)$

So in general it seems that

$E[XY]=\sum_{(x,y) \in X(\Omega) \times Y(\Omega)} xyP(X=x,Y=y)$

I guess this is just some change of indices, but is this true in general?

Comment: nvm, you meant $XY(\Omega)\subset\{4,8,16\}$.

Comment: ??? there should be equality the image of XY is that set.

Comment: What if $X = Y$?